# Commutative discrete cyclic operator groups on topological vector spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a complex Hausdorff separable topological vector space of infinite dimensions. Does there exist a commutative discrete subgroup $A\subset\mathcal{L}(V)$ of continuous operators on $V$ with strong topology, which is cyclic, i.e., there is a vector $v_0\in V$ such that the span $\mathbb{C}\{Av_0\}\subset V$ is dense?

I think I more or less know how to construct it in specific cases (think of permutations in finite $2^n$-dimensional spaces). But I wonder if this question has been considered in the literature, for a specific (but large, not just Hilbert spaces) class or in this generality. Thank you.

Comment: Of course, in the induced topology. Otherwise it wouldn't make sense to stress the topology of the ambient algebra.

Comment: If $T:V\to V$ is an invertible (hyper-) cyclic operator (there is quite some literature about them, i.e., the books of Bayart/Matheron and Grosse-Erdmann/Peris)), is it clear that $\lbrace T^n:n\in\mathbb Z\rbrace$ cannot be discrete in the strong operator topology?

Comment: Thank you very much for introducing to me this concept; I hadn't heard of hypercyclic operators before. I will read on them a little bit before being able to address your question. But it certainly hints at an alternative to my approach by permutations. For instance, I think I can construct a hypercyclic operator on an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space by hand, taking the shift operator (not sure about invertibility though). For Banach spaces it must be subtler, and for general TVS it may be really hard.

Comment: FWIW the wording of the question was fine for me, but that may just reflect the talks I have attended

Comment: Prof. Wengenroth, I think the answer for the case of hypercyclic $T$ is clear. In the strong operator topology, if $v\in V$ is cyclic then the map $T^\mathbb{Z}\ni T^n\mapsto T^nx\in V$ is a homeomorphism onto its range. If $T$ is hypercyclic then this range $\{T^\mathbb{Z}x\}$ is dense. But a discrete subset cannot be dense in $V$. So hypercyclicity is perhaps too strong for these purposes.  I think cyclic operators are rather promising in this respect.